# [RGDBSLAM installation] missing gsl/gsl_linalg.h

Tags: slam, navigation, ubuntu, ros-electric, ubuntu-oneiric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OS: Clean Ubuntu 11.10
ROS version: Electric

I'm trying to install RGBDSLAM for the first time and I'm mystified.  I've followed the installation instructions on the ROS Wiki without issue until step 3.2, but when I execute the line
**rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam**
it fails with this line
**~/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/optimize.h:44:28: fatal error: gsl/gsl_linalg.h: No such file or directory**
Any ideas how to fix this? Let me know if there's more diagnostic info that might help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12911/%5Brgdbslam-installation%5D-missing-gsl/gsl_linalg.h/) by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2012-02-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect you're missing GSL; the GNU scientific library.

The --rosdep-install option should do this for you, but it obviously isn't for some reason. You should file this as a bug against the rgbdslam stack.

In the meantime, you can install GSL with 'sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev'

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-08**:
@Felix: this is a problem because you don't have your stack setup properly; either you need rosdep.yaml in the rgbdslam_freiburg stack, or you need to convert rgbdslam into a unary stack, with both a stack.xml and a manifest.xml.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-02-08**:
Report it here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=rosdep&type=defect&&rosdep

**Comment by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on 2012-02-07**:
Thanks! This worked! How do I go about filing the bug?  Sorry, a bit of a noob here.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-02-07**:
This is correct. However, I can't fix this from the rgbdslam-side, so the bug report should be addressed at rosdep.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-02-21**:
Thanks, ahendrix. I'll fix that soon.